# Prevent perl script from new line

Tags: perl, variables, newline

I have a Perl script:

```
 $i=0;

 while ( ($num = <STDIN>) =~ /\S/ ) {    
     push @lines, $num; $i++;
     print ("$num"x"$i")."\n";
 }
```

It prints this:

```
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
```

But I want it to print this:

```
3 
3
4
4 4
5
5 5 5
```

How can I prevent Perl from printing a new line after every print? 
I have tried this method, as you can see in the code snippet:

```
$num x $i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `chomp($num);` which will remove your input newline at the end of `$num`.

```
my $i=0;
while ( (my $num = <STDIN>) =~ /\S/ ) {
  chomp($num);
  $i++;
  print "$num " x $i, "\n"
}
```

Or you could just:

```
print "$& " x ++$i, "\n" while <STDIN>=~/\d+/;
```

(Also, when asking code questions you should strip down your example to only contain what is relevant. Your `push @lines, $num` can only contribute to confuse potential answerers)

Comment: Thanks!
I added that snippet because I didn't know if that causes any problem with my print.